# How to gather tasks from a list of dictionaries aiohttp async python

Tags: python

I have the following list of dictionary:

```py
[{'id': 1, 'url': 'https://url1.com'}, {'id': 2, 'url': 'https://url2.com'} , {'id': 3, 'url': 'https://url3.com'}]
```

How to use `asyncio.gather` to pass `id` and `url` to a `sync method`?

ideally something like this:

```py
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(*[process(id, url)])) # process is another async method which will need id and url separately
```

if I just had a `list` of url then I know I could easily do something like this:

```py
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(*[process(url) for url in url_list]))
```

tvm

Answer (score -1):

A list comprehension would produce your list of URLs. Something like:

```
x = [{'id': 1, 'url': 'https://url1.com'}, {'id': 2, 'url': 'https://url2.com'} , {'id': 3, 'url': 'https://url3.com'}]
urls = [a_dict['url'] for a_dict in x]
```

If you want `id` and `url` then extract them as a list of tuples:

```
 [ (a_dict['id'], a_dict['url']) for a_dict in x]
 >>>> [(1, 'https://url1.com'), (2, 'https://url2.com'), (3, 'https://url3.com')]
```